# Replace white space with underscore inside double braces

Tags: javascript

How can I replace white space with underscores *only* within double braces?

```
var str = "This is my text {{an other text}} and blabla {{again again}} ...";
```

Desired result:

```
"This is my text {{an_other_text}} and blabla {{again_again}} ..."
```

Comment: Tightened wording.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "This is my text {{an other text}} and blabla {{again again}}";

function replaceChar(str, replacement) {

  if (typeof str !== "string" || typeof replacement !== "string") return str;

  var pattern = /\{\{([^\}\}]+)\}\}/gi,
    arr = str.match(pattern);

  arr.map(function(match) {
    str = str.replace(match, match.replace(/\s/g, replacement));
  });

  return str;
}

console.log(replaceChar(str, "_"));
```

Comment: I don't think `[^\}\}]` does what you seem to think it does. By the way, no need to escape inside character sets.

Comment: @torazaburo Actually i'm not much expert for Regex..so could you tell me what is the problem here or edit the answer please. Thanks :)

Comment: You seem to think this will prevent matching of double right curly brackets. Actually, it will prevent matching of a **single** right curly bracket, since repeating the same character more than once in a character set has no effect.

Comment: In terms of the Regex, would `/{{.*?}}/g` not suffice? Also am a novice regex user but from attempting to answer this question it seemed to work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use this regex:

```
str.replace(/ (?=[\w\s]*}})/g, '_');
```

This is only working if your are using one of these `[A-Za-z0-9_ ]` characters as the text in between the braces.

```
/(?=     # lookahead
[\w\s]*  # possible characters between braces
}})      # until it finds }}
/g       # replace all matches (global)
```

There is no lookbehind necessary because `{` is not one of the possible characters.

If you want to have more possible characters in the text between the braces e. g. `,` use this regex:

```
str.replace(/ (?=[A-Za-z0-9_ ]*}})/g, '_');
```

Add `,` into `[A-Za-z0-9_ ]` => `[A-Za-z0-9_ ,]`